# Pandas Pivot Table and Matplotlib bar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to use Matplotlib to make a Bar graph with different color.
So far, I have a Pandas Pivot Table which looks like this:

```
              productType
physicalType             
Chassis                54
Fan                   295
Module                154
Power Supply           91
```

I can get a Bar graph but the color are all the same for each series.
How can I have different colors for different series ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do it is to use `T` and pandas plot:

```
df.T.plot.bar()
```

[image]

Another way is to use `itertuples`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df1 = df.reset_index()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for r in df1.itertuples():
    ax.bar(r[0],r[2],label=r[1])

_ = plt.xticks(df1.index,df1.physicalType)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful example !